# Can I interpret control variable's coefficients in linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, multivariate-analysis

imagine I want to estimate a regression model (let's say OLS for simplicity's sake) using observational data. I include a number of controls that might confound the relationship. For example, I might estimate the effect of the number of storks in an area on the number of births. While the initial relationship might be positive, it disappears once I control for urbanness.

In my understanding, the control variables' coefficients are not interesting, as I include them only to restrict the variation in the dependent to estimate the relationship of interest. Hence, in my little example, I couldn't interpret the effect of urbanness on childbirths, as I did not include relevant controls, and - even worse - might bias the estimate with the inclusion of the theoretically unrelated number of storks. Yet, it seems to be standard practice to interpret the controls when reporting results/not have a main independent but estimate several effects at once.

Can you point me to an authoritative source explaining this or explain why my reasoning is off?

Comment: You seem to make several claims.  Could you tell us more specifically which aspect of your reasoning you are asking about?

Comment: The idea that you can only correctly interpret the coefficient of a single independent variable at a time

Comment: What does that mean? The coefficients of variables in a multiple regression depend on the other variables in the model, so mathematically what you write is impossible: you can interpret the coefficients *only* in the context of all the variables.

Comment: It seems to me the important question is whether there really are more storks in urban areas...

Comment: My point is that to correctly identify an effect Y ~ X, you need to include all theoretically related confounders. But for these confounders, one cannot interpret their effect on the dependent, because the confounders for their relationship with the dependent Y are not included. Hence, you should only interpret the effect of the main independent variable. The point is theoretical rather than statistical I guess.

Comment: I get your point, and they do teach in intro causal inference that regression coefficients on confounders are not meaningful for interpretation as "treatment effect". That being said, in applied research this is standard practice! If you're not well-exposed to applied studies, you're not going to believe how common this is (at least in applied econ), and who keeps making this "mistake" in what journals! (Spoiler: Top journals, by e.g. nobel laureate or equivalently accomplished economists! I'd be very surprised if they haven't been told they can't do this in their first econometrics class!)

Comment: Great Q.  I control for X2, a confounder of the X1-Y relationship. I control for X3, a confounder of the X2-Y relationship (and thus of the X1-Y relationship too).  I am getting closer to an accurate model. But close enough to call the effects causal?  It’s a slippery matter, very context-dependent. A philosopher might call it a problem of infinite regression:  “what does that turtle rest on?”  There is no general stopping rule.

Comment: But this would bias the original relationship of interest. My point is that you can only create a theoretical model for one variable and control for potential confounders. When you start controlling for confounders of the confounders, you will introduce more bias. Hence we only include confounders for the relationship of interest and only obtain ONE meaningful estimate - the estimate for the one independent for which we include confounders. The confounders' coefficients are not meaningful

Answer (score 1):

The regression does not know which variables are "main" and which are "control variables".  You can interpret all of them in the same way.

In an observational study, even with control variables, you cannot, strictly speaking, suppose there is an "effect" - only a relationship. And the same is true for all the variables. You never know if you have controlled for all the relevant variables.

It is true, though, that adding control variables eliminates those variables from being the reason for the relationship between the main variable and the DV.